# OnSelect datepicker not working

Tags: 7, datetime

I am having a problem with this function, it simply is now working. I have a module with just a basic form and im using the date module to get the datepicker to pop up and that works fine, but when I select a date from the datepicker the alert is not firing.

this is what i have in my theme js file.

```
//id for nay_date input field     
$('#edit-nay-date-datepicker-popup-0').datepicker(function() {
              onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
              alert(selectedDate);
            }
        });
```

and this is the field i have in my module

```
$form[['nay_date'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Date',
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#description' => '',
    '#required' => TRUE,    
);
```

Comment: did you wrap your JS in a drupal-friendly version of jQuery's Document ready function ? Does Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools console show any errors ?

Comment: actually yeah i do I get 

SyntaxError: function statement requires a name
onSelect: function(selectedDate) {

Answer (score 1):

I use it without a function as the argument like: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2SErg/)

```
//id for nay_date input field     
$('#edit-nay-date-datepicker-popup-0').datepicker({
          onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
          alert(selectedDate);
        }
    });
```